# Timing mistake in Elixir GenServer tutorial?

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server

I'm going through the Elixir "Getting Started" tutorial, where the following code snippet is used:

```
test "removes buckets on exit", %{registry: registry} do
  KV.Registry.create(registry, "shopping")
  {:ok, bucket} = KV.Registry.lookup(registry, "shopping")
  Agent.stop(bucket)
  assert KV.Registry.lookup(registry, "shopping") == :error
end
```

Now, `create/2` uses the `cast` operation whereas `lookup` uses `call`. So that means that an asynchronous call is executed and then immediately after that, a synchronous call which assumes the async action was performed successfully. Could timing issues result in the test failing when the code itself is correct, or is there some aspect of `cast` and `call` that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since GenServer's process all messages sequentially, the `lookup` call would block until the previous `cast` completed so there should be no timing issues.